# Angular 8 not change header after navigate

Tags: angular

i want to change header when user is logged in, but i'm not able. Redirect works good and the center of page change, but the header don't.

This is function when click Login button in auth component

```
 LoginFormSubmit(LoginForm){
return this.http.post(environment.laravel_api+'/login',LoginForm.value).subscribe(
  data => this.afterLogin(data) ,
  error => console.log(error)
);
```

}

afterLogin(data){

```
this.user.setSession(data['user']);
this.route.navigateByUrl('');
```

}

Here is my header component:

```
 session;
  constructor(private  user: UserService, private http: HttpClient, private route: Router) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("Dentro");
    this.session = this.user.getSession();
  }


  Logout(){
    localStorage.clear();
    this.afterLogout();
  }

  afterLogout(){
    this.route.initialNavigation();
  }
```

And here is the userserice:

```
 constructor() { }



  setSession(session_data){
    localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(session_data));

  }

  getSession(){
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'));

  }
```

Comment: I would like to see the component with the `router-outlet`.

Comment: ```<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>```

Comment: header component is already loaded when you check "this.session = this.user.getSession();" Do you see Dentro again into console ?

Comment: Ok, I see. You must have the header in the component that route to.

Comment: @DrilonHametaj sorry I have miss understand you

Comment: @PivaGregory yes i see "Dentro" but only one time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement something like this in your user service:

```
@Injectable()
class UserService() {

    private _session= new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

    setSession(session_data: string) {
        this._session.next(session_data);
    }

    get session() {
        return this._session.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Then in the `HeaderComponent`:

```
<button>{{ (userService.session | async).firstName }}</button>
```

Explanation: prefer not using `localStorage` to hold the session, as it may cause the Angular app to be out of sync with the backend (when the session expires). Prefer sending a cookie from the backend, and let the Angular app retrieve user info every time the app starts or is refreshed.

An Angular service is a singleton (one instance for the whole app) so it can hold a state and share it with any component. The `BehaviorSubject` helps notify the subscribers when the login state has changed.

Comment: Thank you, but how can i do the logout?

Comment: The logout can be done by notifying the backend which will clear the cookie. If there is no network, you can also delete the cookie from the frontend.